# Which testing-framework for Javascript supports Testing without a browser?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, continuous-integration

For Javascript some testing-frameworks exist, like JSUnit or js-test-driver. They are fine, but they run the tests in a browser. That's fine, especially to verify your webapp is running in different browsers. But on out continuous-integration-server no window-system (and no browser) is installed. So is there a way to run the tests without the usage of a browser? The best would be to use one of the existing frameworks, so that developers can locally run the tests in their browsers and the continuous-integration-system runs them browserless.

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but I would suggest testing the thing in a real browser. This is what the end-users will see, so this should be tested. What OS is the CI installed on?

Comment: The CI is installed on linux, but without a X. So testing in a browser is not possible on the CI-server. In the browsers it will be tested by the developers anyway, but I want to add the tests also to CI.

Comment: How about phantomjs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) which is used by several UI-testing framework like [WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/webdriver/)

Answer (score 1):

[jsTest](http://thinkpond.org/articles/2008/jstest-intro.shtml) can be run command line or as an eclipse plugin.

However, be careful, you will not get 100% code coverage using a tool like this if you need to support multiple browsers. Each browser implements JavaScript differently (i.e.: IE). Therefore, the only way to fully test your JavaScript is to run the tests in all browsers that you support.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say you can't get 100% coverage.  Coverage means that the code gets executed.  The problem you point to (cross-browser compatibility) is that the same code might mean (and do) different things in different execution environments.  The implication of that is that if you have 100% coverage in Firefox, it might not tell you all you want to know about the code's behavior in IE.  You can get 100% coverage without getting 100% knowledge.  (And even 100% coverage in all browsers is not the same as 100% knowledge, but that's a different issue.)

Comment: This was 5 years ago. Web development back then was full of browser-dependent bifurcations since the APIs were so disparate. If you ran your test in Firefox, some command line runner, etc. you could not execute _any_ of the code in the other branch that handled another browser. Since you're leaving half your branches untested, you cannot claim 100% code coverage. Nowadays, the landscape is a lot different. I honestly can't remember the last time I had to do different things for different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following articles:

- [JavaScript Unit Testing with Hudson and JasmineBDD](http://skaug.no/ingvald/2010/10/javascript-unit-testing.html)
- [JavaScript BDD, with Jasmine, without a browser](http://www.build-doctor.com/2010/12/08/javascript-bdd-jasmine/)

In addition, we have a jsTestDriver server running with a couple of web browsers (as remote console runners) as a resource for Jenkins, so you can have CI with testing in web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Canoo WebTest can be run without a browser. It's basically a frontend-testing framework but can be used to test JavaScript as well:

http://webtest.canoo.com/

Answer (score 0):

JSpec can be run without a browser (using Rhino). But also supports being run in browsers as well.

http://visionmedia.github.com/jspec/

It also provides a nice specification style syntax:

```
describe 'ShoppingCart'   
  describe 'addProduct'   
    it 'should add a product'  
      cart.addProduct('cookie') 
      cart.addProduct('icecream') 
      cart.should.have 2, 'products'   
    end   
  end 
end
```

By running all your unit tests outside of a browser, you also get the benefits of ensuring separation of your logic from the html/presentation layer (useful for web apps, possibly overkill for small scripts).

Comment: The jspec project is dead and, before their site disappeared entirely, recommended Jasmine instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912312/jspec-no-longer-supported

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine will run quite happily inside of node.js.