# JSpec no longer supported?

Tags: javascript, testing, node.js, bdd, jspec

Coming from the Ruby community I'm looking for a BDD-testing framework for Javascript/Node.js.

I was JSpec and thought it would be the right choice because I used RSpec in Ruby.

But on their GitHub page http://github.com/visionmedia/jspec it says it's no longer supported.

They are abandoning this project?

Does this mean I shouldn't use it since it's not being maintained anylonger?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you take a look at either:

- [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) and [Jasmine-species](http://rudylattae.github.com/jasmine-species/)

  or
- [Vows.js](http://vowsjs.org) and [Kyuri](https://github.com/nodejitsu/kyuri)

Alternatively check out [Cucumis](https://github.com/noblesamurai/cucumis)

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript teams I've worked with use QUnit. They just ignore the word "test".

JSpec's site recommends Jasmine now. I've not seen Jasmine used before; a quick look at its API tells me it might be more intuitive than QUnit. I like their principles, and their documentation is clear. Makes me want to pick up JavaScript again...

My vote is for Jasmine.